# How to architect an API first multi app platform?

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, nosql

I am trying to build an API first web app that has two parts:

- Part A: The Project Management App. This would be built using php/mysql. One of the table in the mysql DB will be the **users** table where all users information will be stored viz username, password, email etc.
- Part B: The online chat App. The users of the project management system will be able to chat among themselves. This will be built using nodejs/mongo. The mongodb DB would store the chat transcripts of each users and so would have a **users** collection containing the user details. The **users** collection would contain the same user information that the mysql users table has viz username, password, email etc.

Now, i have a couple of questions in terms of the architecture of this app.

Question 1: Is it at all a wise idea to maintain two different sources to store the user's information? The reason why I wanted to have a replica of the users table in the MongoDB as well is because since there will be too many reads and writes happening in the chat app so its best we use a nosql DB. (Lets assume here that my app will be used heavily going forward)

Question 2: If the answer to Question 1 is "Yes", how do we make sure of data consistency? I have thought of two approaches to achieve this:

Option A: Since we are using the API first approach, so during the registration of a user when the CREATE user api call is made, it will add the user in both mysql and mongodb databases.

Option B: I setup a cron that will sync the data between the mysql users table and the mongodb users collection periodically.

Can someone please throw some light on this and tell me if my approaches are right and that if I am going towards the right direction.

Many thanks

Comment: Caching generally is, of course, one of the hardest problems in computer engineering. Should you build a greenfield application (a new application) with elaborate custom-built caching in it? (Your example suggests keeping copies of vital data in both Mongo and RDMS: that's caching.)   I say *no.* I say, *keep it simple*  until you have a million users, then design your caching to solve your real problems. Look up the acronym **YAGNI** and take it seriously. Remember that both RMDSs and Mongo are built to perform well.

Comment: Hmm..so if i understood what you meant, i should store the user details only in mysql and the chat logs in mongodb? But then, i'd also need to store the friends list of a user,  should that also be store in mysql?

Comment: Choose either MySQL or Mongo to support all your app's data needs. Then make it work as well as you possibly can. Then scale it to a million users. Then figure out whether you need to add data caching to boost latency and throughput. You may find MySQL now, MySQL + Redis later, is a good combination.

Comment: ok i got you. Can you please tell me a use case when i'd need mongodb over mysql or any other RDBMS?

Comment: Generally one chooses a whole tech stack. The point is to adopt development tools--tools you and your team know how to use--that play well with one another already. Php and MySQL is a popular stack.  Mongo / Express / Angular / Node.js is another. C# / SQL Server / dotnet is a third. Java servlets with any JDBC database is another.  *Get your product built!* Don't waste a lot of time trying to build your own interfaces between this language and that database.